# Trouble overriding toString() in Java

Tags: java, string, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

I have an assignment to practice interfaces, abstract classes, subclasses and inheritance for my Java class. In my abstract superclass (called *Matrix*), I have to override the toString() method (using the same signature) so that it prints all elements of an array separated by a space and lines separated by a line break. Like this:

```
 public String toString(){

    String result="";

    for(int x=0; x<nRows(); x++){
        for(int y=0; y<nColumns(); y++){
            result+=""+get(x,y)+" ";
        }
        result+="\n";
    }
    return result;
}
```

So far so good, I think. Then, in one of the subclasses (*FullMatrix*) of *Matrix*, I have a static method generating random numbers to fill a m x n matrix. The method is as follows:

```
    public static FullMatrix randomMatrix(int m, int n, double low, double high){

    FullMatrix resultMatrix = new FullMatrix(m,n);
    for(int x=0; x<m; x++){
        for(int y=0; y<n; y++){
            resultMatrix.set(x,y,Math.round(low+Math.random()*(high-low)));

        }
    }
    return resultMatrix;
}
```

Again, no problems so far. BUT, in my main method, in another class, when I call the static method *randomMatrix* like this:

```
FullMatrix a = new FullMatrix(4,4);
    a.randomMatrix(4,4,-3,5);
```

it returns me a Matrix full of zeros. I thought the problem was with my randomizing algorithm, but no. I started debugging, and it turns out my resultMatrix from the method randomMatrix uses the toString method and becomes one big string (which is supposed to print the result), so I can't assign new random values to the elements. The weird thing is toString() is never called in randomMatrix. So why does resultMatrix use the toString method? I tried commenting out the toString override in my superclass, and it solves the problem, but, in my assignment, I have to print the matrices this way.

Help? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The call `a.randomMatrix(4,4,-3,5);` returns a `FullMatrix` object, but you are not using the return value, so it just gets discarded. Do something like this: `FullMatrix a = FullMatrix.randomMatrix(4,4,-3,5);`.

Comment: You're calling a static method on an instance. Did you perhaps mean something along the lines of `FullMatrix a = FullMatrix.randomMatrix(4,4,-3,5)`?

Comment: `toString` doesn't seem your issue.

Comment: @Jesper Thanks a lot! That did the trick! Everything works now!

Comment: I just realized the debugging showed the matrix using my new definition of toString because it usually probably displays variable results as strings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not call static methods using an object, since it doesn't make sense.

The matrices `a` and `resultMatrix` are two independent objects. To get a random matrix, call:

```
Matrix m = FullMatrix.randomMatrix(...);
```